# How does load balancing work when swarmmode is enabled for traefik v2.0?

Tags: load-balancing, docker-swarm, traefik

**Docker Swarm** has its own *loadbalancing* method and also **traefik** has its own. In this case; when I enable the swarm mode in **traefik** what is expected when *loadbalancing* is needed?